# adding two values task in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am a student and new to verilog. I understand what these codes mean and they seem to be working for me. However, I am having troubles with the task.

```
module add_two_values_task(output reg sum,output reg cout, input ain,input bin);

task add_two_values;
    output [3:0] sum;
    output out;
    input [3:0]ain;
    input [3:0]bin;
    reg [3:0] sum;
    reg out;
    {out, sum} = ain + bin;
endtask

always @(ain or bin) begin
    add_two_values(cout,sum,ain,bin);
end

endmodule
```

However, when I run my simulation:

[image]

When I run the simulation, I suppose to get a value for z, however, I ended up with getting letter 'z' for the sum. Did I write my code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot about few very important syntax elements. And messed the order of arguments in your task.

```
module add_two_values_task(output reg [3:0] sum,output reg cout, input [3:0] ain, input [3:0] bin);  // You need to declare signals width

task add_two_values;
    output [3:0] sum;
    output out;
    input [3:0]ain;
    input [3:0]bin;
    reg [3:0] sum;
    reg out;
    {out, sum} = ain + bin;
endtask

always @(ain or bin) begin
    add_two_values(sum,cout,ain,bin);  // You messed order of arguments here
end

endmodule
```

Firstly in `module` declaration you need to declare bit width of input and output signals (otherwise signals will be assumed length of 1 bit). Secondly in your task call you messed order of arguments. Should work now.